# Error in Custom DibsPaymentMethodService Overriding ProcessCallback

Tags: c#, umbraco, umbraco-ucommerce, dibs

I'm trying to customize the dialogue between uCommerce and DIBS to allow ticket registrations.

So far, I've succeeded in copying the DibsPageBuilder and adding the maketicket parameter. However, I need to customize the callback made to the function ProcessCallcack in the DibsPaymentMethodService class.

I copied the ProcessCallback and its content carefully and added it to my custom class, but when I run the checkout pipeline I keep getting the following error:

```
 UCommerce.Pipelines.PipelineException: Exception occoured while processing pipeline 
'UCommerce.Pipelines.Checkout.CheckoutPipeline'. See inner exception for details. 
 ---&gt; System.Security.SecurityException: Payment insufficient to cover order total 
 for OrderGuid xxx. Please ensure that payments cover the entire value of the order 
 before checking out. at 
 Commerce.Pipelines.Checkout.ValidatePaymentsMadeAgainstOrderTotalTask.Execute(PurchaseOrder subject) 
 at UCommerce.Pipelines.Pipeline`1.Execute(T subject) --- End of inner exception 
 stack trace ---...
```

I don't get why the checkout pipeline fail to succeed when I manually override the ProcessCallback with the same code the function usually is made of. In other words, if I don't override ProcessCallback the function runs smoothly, but then I don't get to do my customization. I have to say, that the error occurs before I customize anything.

My current uCommerce platform runs version 2.6.1. The code I've copied is:

```
 public override void ProcessCallback(Payment payment)
 {
    if (payment.PaymentStatusId != 10000001)
            return;
    DibsPaymentMethodServiceConfigurationSection instance = 
            DibsPaymentMethodServiceConfigurationSection.Instance;
    string s = HttpContext.Current.Request["transact"];
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(s))
            throw new ArgumentException("transact must be present in query string.");
    int result;
    if (!int.TryParse(s, out result))
            throw new FormatException("transact must be a valid int32");
    PaymentStatusCode paymentStatusCode = PaymentStatusCode.Authorized;
    if (instance.UseMd5)
    {
            string parameter1 = this.GetParameter("authkey", "When using md5 \"{0}\" cannot be null or empty", new string[1]
            {
            "authkey"
            });
            string parameter2 = this.GetParameter("currency", "When using md5 \"{0}\" cannot be null or empty", new string[1]
            {
            "currency"
            });
            string parameter3 = this.GetParameter("amount", "When using md5 \"{0}\" cannot be null or empty", new string[1]
            {
            "amount"
            });
            int currencyNumber = new CurrencyCodeTranslater().FromIsoCode(parameter2);
            string postMd5Key = new DibsMd5Computer().GetPostMd5Key(result.ToString(), parameter3, currencyNumber);
            if (!parameter1.Equals(postMd5Key))
                   paymentStatusCode = PaymentStatusCode.Declined;
    }
    payment.PaymentStatus = PaymentStatus.Get((object) paymentStatusCode);
    payment.TransactionId = result.ToString();
    this.ProcessPaymentRequest(new PaymentRequest(payment.PurchaseOrder, payment));
}
```

Many thanks in advance.

/brinck10

Comment: I would start looking at whats going on in: `ValidatePaymentsMadeAgainstOrderTotalTask`.

Comment: Also ... you don't mention what you need to change. I think most of the methods can be overriden so no use really for making new classes.